# Canvas - Fill a shape created with multiple paths

Tags: javascript, canvas, turtle-graphics

## What I want to do

I would like to draw a custom shape (for example a simple rectangle) which has different colors for each edge. I can do it with four paths, it works like a charm. BUT, in this way, it seems I can not fill the shape.

Trying the other way, I can draw the shape with one path and fill it, BUT in this case, I can not use different colors for the edges, because the last `fillStyle` will override the previous ones, even if I stroke the subpaths individually.

Is it possible to mix the two, by coloring subpaths individually, or by filling a shape consisting multiple paths?

Comment: Draw it multiple times? One for the fill and theb every edges on its own for the strokes (remember to call beginPath for each new path)

Comment: It's not that easy. I have step-by-step execution.

Comment: Can you be more clear then, possibly with a sample code? As I read it, you've got points to make your path, let's say a triangle p1,p2,p3. Then why can't you just `fillStyle=c0; beginPath(); moveTo(p1); lineTo(p2); lT(p2); lT(p3); fill(); fS=c1; bP(); mT(p1); lT(p2); stroke(); fS=c2; bP(); mT(p2); lT(p3); stroke(); fS=c3; bP(); mT(p3); lT(p1); stroke();` ?

Answer (score 1):

Use different "layers" on the canvas, one for the filled with color shape, and a new one for each color path you have, z-index doesn't work on canvas, just make sure you draw what goes underneath first, and just wrap everything on a group `<g>` tag to make it easier to manipulate

Comment: I use the `<canvas>` element, not SVG.

Comment: no need for svg, you can overlap paths on canvas as well

Comment: I can not fill the shape, because it does not exist before the strokes.

Answer (score 1):

After some experiment, I managed to solve my problem. It is not an ideal solution, because it has some overhead, but it works fine.

In the beginning of the drawing operation, I store the target coordinates in an array, and draw the whole stuff again and again. Each run is a new path. With `.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-over"` I can draw the lines **under** the existing ones, so each line can have a different color.

At the end of the drawing operation, the array contains all the coordinates of the shape, so the `.fill()` method can fill the path.

I hope it can help others:

```js
// get the canvas context
var ctx = document.getElementById("myCanvas").getContext("2d");

// init shape array
var shape = [];
shape.push({
  x: 0,
  y: 0
}); // or any other starting point

// let's try
draw(20, 20);
draw(40, 40);
draw(60, 60);

// this is how we draw
function draw(x, y) {
  // this is important
  // see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-over";

  // this is just to be more visible
  ctx.lineWidth = 10;

  // get a random color
  ctx.strokeStyle = myRandomColor();

  // save target coordinates
  shape.push({
    x: x,
    y: y
  });

  // reset the path
  ctx.beginPath();

  // jump to the start point
  ctx.moveTo(shape[0].x, shape[0].y);

  // draw the whole stuff
  for (var i = 0; i < shape.length; i++) {
    ctx.lineTo(shape[i].x, shape[i].y);
  }
  ctx.stroke();
}

function myRandomColor() {
  var colors = ["red", "green", "blue", "yellow", "pink"];
  var rand = Math.round(Math.random() * 5);
  return colors[rand];
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```